# Debian installer can't access eMMC Card

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, debian, grub

so for some backstory: a couple days ago, i bought a cheap laptop (a Lenovo Ideapad 1 with an AMD Athlon silver) and planned to install gnu/linux on it, replacing windows 10. previously i set up a dual-boot with the Intel-CPU equivalent of this laptop, no problem.

however, i've tried to for too long now, so i need some external advice.

i've tried disabling secure boot, enabling bios backflash, enabling legacy mode, and every permutation of those, as well as ticking on and off every setting in the boot menu

it's not a problem with the USB i'm installing from either: i've tried the network-install, the DVD image and checked the checksums both times. i've also tried the USB with the Intel-equivalent of the laptop, to which the partitions on the eMMC showed up in GRUB no problem.

the GRUB command `ls -l` displays the disk too: 
`No known filesystem detected - Sector size 512B - total size 61071360KiB`
        `` Partition hd1,gpt4: Filesystem type ntfs - Label `WINRE_DRV' ``
        `` Partition hd1,gpt3: Filesystem type ntfs - Label `Windows' ``
        `Partition hd1,gpt2: No known filesystem detected`
        `` Partition hd1,gpt1: Filesystem type fat - Label `SYSTEM_DRV' ``

(i've excluded some lines and some error messages that didn't affect the detection in the Debian Installer (i.e. worked on my other laptop))

i've tried mounting the drive manually within a live debian system, but `fdisk` doesn't even return the drive...

so the problem (from lots of scrolling through forums for an answer) could be

- something to do with AHCI,
- the grub missing files,
- the actual EMMC card hardware/drivers,
- or something that can be solved using the "BIOS Advanced Settings" menu, which i've heard unlocks if you push the entire QWERTY keyboard in order while holding the boot button (i'm desperate)

i'm slowly losing my sanity, so thanks in advance for any useful advice

Comment: Sometimes it really is a driver problem and Debian known to lack behind a bit. Have you tried a live version of some distro that has more recent kernels available? E.g. Mint or Fedora (or Debian testing?) with kernel 5.+.